# How to change the default width of the VerticalScrollBar which is derived from the ScrollControl?

Tags: c#, winforms, scrollbar

I have added the vertical scrollbar which is derived from the ScrollBar class.
I have override the UpdateScrollInfo using the following code snippet.

```
    protected new void UpdateScrollInfo()  
    {
        NativeScrollAPI.SCROLLINFO si;
        if (this.IsHandleCreated && this.Enabled)
            base.UpdateScrollInfo();
        else if (this.reflectParent != null)
        {
            si = new NativeScrollAPI.SCROLLINFO();
            si.cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(NativeScrollAPI.SCROLLINFO));
            si.fMask = (int) (SIF.ALL | SIF.DISABLENOSCROLL);
            si.nMin = this.Minimum;
            si.nMax = this.Maximum;
            si.nPage = Math.Min(this.LargeChange,( (this.Maximum - this.Minimum) + 1));
            if (this.RightToLeft == RightToLeft.Yes) 
                si.nPos = this.ReflectPosition(this.Value);
            else
                si.nPos = this.Value;

            si.nTrackPos = 0;
            NativeScrollAPI.SetScrollInfo(this.reflectParent.Handle, this.ScrollInfoBar, ref si, true);
        }
    }
```

Now my question is, this loads the scrollbar with the default width of 17. How can i change this default value?
[image]

Comment: I am creating the control using the following code,
`[ToolboxItem(false)]
internal class SystemScrollBar : ScrollBar, IScrollBar
{}`

Answer (score 1):

You can change width of scroll bar by using width:

`yourScrollBar.width = 34; //34 is example width`

Answer (score 1):

In design view,

Select your scroll bar and go in the `properties` panel

Find `Size` in the `Layout` tab, in `Size` change your `width`

Comment: Hi ghostwar,
Thanks for your suggestion,

I need not showing this control in designer therefore i have set the ToolBoxItem(false) attribute for this control.

Comment: Hi Adhi, I think Parpil's suggestion would work best for you,